# Перенос программ на Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Как осуществляется перенос программы, на другой компьютер, в которой есть модули из pip, например [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5)?

Comment: Что именно имеете в виду под переносом? С одного рабочего окружения в другое?

Comment: Ну даже банально, я хочу перенести скрипт, написанный с pip-овской либой с одного компа на другой. Это, получается, мне надо на новом компе все разворачивать с нуля?

Comment: что значит "перенос"? "Как перенести среду разработки?" или "Как установить программу на Питоне"? Как вы другие программы, которые Qt используют ставите (на любом языке)?

Comment: Вот я написал приложение, которое читает vk, к примеру. Все состоит из одного файла vkreader.py, в котором из pip подтягивается модуль vk. Если я этот скрипт возьму и перенесу на другую машину (предварительно на ней есть python), то там он не заработает, потому что снова нужно подтягивать модуль. Таких модулей может быть море и очень не удобно при переносе в другую среду заново все подтягивать. Есть ли способ брать и хотя бы подтягивать автоматически, что ли.

Comment: @PirateNinja если хотите, чтобы зависимости полумагически сами подтягивались, [попробуйте fades](https://fades.readthedocs.io). Есть много опций для разных случаев (начните с команд, предоставляемых pip таких как `pip freeze` и  `pip install -r requirements.txt`). Попробуйте ваш случай подробно описать (к примеру упомяните: GUI или CLI создаёте, есть ли не-Питон зависимости, какая OS). Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого.

Answer (score 3):

Можно упаковать программу в exe. Только часто это бывает проблемно осуществить, особенно со сторонними модулями.

Для упаковки можно использовать [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) или [cx_Freeze](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html)

http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1462380.html#post7689543

Comment: Ну пока что единственный вариант для решения проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Готовых решений из коробки нет. Имеется только вариант использовать вещи на подобии PyInstaller для создания исполняющих файлов. Они автоматически будут подтягивать нужные библиотеки. Немного криво для такого языка с такими возможностями, но другого пути не вижу.